# Model is added in autoload file of Laravel but I facing issue while calling its code

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am new to Laravel I am trying to call a function from my model but facing the following issue

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError   (E_ERROR)
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Role' not found
```

While model is already loaded by autoloader

```
'App\\Role' => $baseDir . '/app/Models/Role.php'
```

My controller has the following code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class RoleController extends Controller
{
public function CreateRole()
{
    $owner = new Role();
    $owner->name         = 'owner';
    $owner->display_name = 'Project Owner'; // optional
    $owner->description  = 'User is the owner of a given project'; // optional
    $owner->save();

    $admin = new Role();
    $admin->name         = 'admin';
    $admin->display_name = 'User Administrator'; // optional
    $admin->description  = 'User is allowed to manage and edit other users'; // optional
    $admin->save();
}
```

}

Thanks,

Aisha Zafar

Comment: do you have the use in the begining of the file?

Comment: I just called it like that http://127.0.0.1:8000/create_role and it throws the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the begining of the file try to do this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Role;                  // <-- Add this

class RoleController extends Controller
{
 ...
```

Comment: after adding that line I get this error This cache store does not support tagging

Comment: Do you have a database configured?

Comment: Try to open a bash on the project root folder and run this 
`php artisan tinker ` and
`DB::connection()->getPdo();`

Comment: CONNECTION_STATUS: "Connection OK; waiting to send."

Comment: I fixed the issue by changing  CACHE_DRIVER=file to  CACHE_DRIVER=array

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the model class has this namespace:

```
namespace App;
```

Then run `composer du` command and use the full namespace:

```
$owner = new \App\Role;
```

Or add `use` to the top of the controller:

```
use App\Role;
```